# How to join a cell text with another cell that contains text already in excel?

Tags: excel, formula

Here is what im trying to do. Lets say I have cell A2 that contains text "Hello world" and cell A1 contains "Mike", how can i replace the word "world" in A2 with the one in A1. I tried the REPLACE function but not getting the result i need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this if you always want to switch the part of the word after a space.

```
Concatenate(Left(A2;Find(" ";A2));A1)
```

If you want to do the same thing with the same source cell, then do this:

```
Concatenate(Left($A$2;Find(" ";$A$2));A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"World",A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what if "Hello World" is in B1 and i need to auto fill for more rows?

Comment: 1 that is not what you asked.  2. You would need to make absolute the references that need to be made absolute and refer to the correct cells.  Then drag down.